# Zero representations file found in "mymodelingproject" EMF

Tags: eclipse, emf

I have the following error: `Zero representations file found in "mymodelingproject" A modeling project must contain one.` (Type: Modeling Marker)

I have selected Design Viewpoint, and created my entity class diagram (.aird) in eclipse with EMF. I have my .ecore model and my .genmodel too.

Comment: Have the same question !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something with your project Nature is corrupt.
Removing the Line in the `.project` file:

```
<nature>org.eclipse.sirius.nature.modelingproject</nature>
```

Save it and then add it back in, sometimes helps.